# Using two top constraint with various priority values

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, constraints

I've got a pretty trivial case.
There is a Container (light gray color) that has a HeaderLabel (lines = 0) with 16px margins and View (blue color).

If there some value for HeaderLabel it should place above the View.

[image]

Else if we have no value for HeaderLabel it should disappear and View sticks to top of the Container.

[image]

I tried to create two View.Top constraint to HeaderLabel and Container (constant >= 0) with various priority.

[image]

And remove HeaderLabel in the code if there is no text value for it

```
if (!text) {
    [headerLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But it seems not working. It just shows the gap between top of the Container and View

[image]

How can I manage this case using IB? Or it should be solved by another way?

Comment: You need to create an IBOutlet for your constraint and set it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this method, which is making the scroller view constraint larger so that the scroll view will cover the label and the gap. 
First, create an IBOutlet for your constraint.

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *NAME;`

Then, connect it with the vertical constraint of your scrollView.

After that, check the label value and set the constraint to 0 is the value is nil.

```
if (!text){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animation:^{
        self.NAME.constant = THE HEIGHT OF SCROLLVIEW + THE GAP;
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 view(viewLabel) with leading,trailing & top to superview and bottom to view(blue view).

for label set in viewLabel with constraint leading,trailing,top & bottom to superview  and set label number of line = 0. 
set value  if any

```
label.text = @"Value";
```

either set

```
label.text = @"";
```

auto layout manage automatically height of label and its superView(viewLabel) and after set value     [self.view layoutIfNeeded]